# JScrollPane won't scroll - Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

So I'm developing an application. I have a huge problem, and I know I'm probably overlooking something stupid, but my scollpanes aren't scrolling. Could someone please checkout the following code and tell me what I did wrong?

```
rotationPanel = new JPanel();
rotationPanel.setLayout(null);
rotationLabels = new JLabel[countStarters(team)];
resetXY(5,5);
for(int i = 0; i < countStarters(team); i++){
    rotationLabels[i] = new JLabel(team.rotation.get(i).getName());
    rotationLabels[i].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    addComp(rotationLabels[i], rotationPanel, labelX, labelY, labelSize);
    labelY += 25;
}

//Other Code in between

rotationBar = new JScrollPane(rotationPanel);
rotationBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
rotationBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
rotationBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(520, 150));
addComp(rotationBar, this, 15, 75, new Dimension(520, 150));

//addComp method:
public void addComp(JComponent comp, JComponent panel, int xPos, int yPos, Dimension size){
    comp.setLocation(xPos,yPos);
    comp.setSize(size);
    panel.add(comp);
}
```

The resetXY() method just sets the x and y position for the components

Any help would be appreciated

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: uff it's not recommended to use `null` layout

Comment: Everyone says that. I prefer to use null layout for GUI's like this. More control

Comment: and when you resize it works well? in other resolutions too?

Comment: Ive set it to not resize. It's staying one size. Although does the layout affect the JScrollPane?

Comment: i don't know, i always use layout managers, but you can always make a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can test your issue!

Comment: And the use of null layouts never cause you problems with components not working the way you expect them to? Personally, I can't stand non-resizable windows, I use a non-standard font size and it just screws everything up. Swing has being designed to work with layout managers. Failing to utilise this part of the API will produce undesirable results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JScrollPane` uses either the components preferredSize or if implemented [`Scrollable#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) to determine what size the scroll pane and its view port can be. When the viewport is larger the the scroll pane, the scroll bars will appear

The Swing API has being designed around the use of the layout manager, choosing to do without the  will cause you no end of problems and additional work.

Layout managers help you over come the difference between systems, including font rendering, DPI, screen sizes and rendering pipelines to mention a few.

Comment: So if I were to use a layout manager. Which one will give me the most control? I've used Grid and Gridbag and haven't really been impressed. I was thinking of useing Spring, but I'm not too familiar with it. I need one that will let me place most components right where I want them

Comment: I prefer GridBagLayout, but I also use BorderLayout and GridLayout on a regular bases and compound them. You may consider taking a look at MigLayiut as well. Don't forget, you can use an EmptyBorder and with GridBagLayout, insets to pad your components

Comment: Good point. I didn't think about that when I was considering gridbag. I usually like using null just for the amount of control, but these scrollbars are proving to be a pain. Onto google I go!

Comment: How a GUI appears in your computer is unlikely to be how it appears on someone else's ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your JPanel needs to have its size set, otherwise it will shrink to fit the JScrollPane.

Comment: Nope. Scrollpane doesn't care what "size" the panel is, it uses a different means to determine what size the panel, and the scroll pane should be...